# ¿puedo utilizar el system session manager de una instancia ec2 de aws abriendo el puerto https + mi ip pública?

Tags: aws, ec2, security

He probado que abriendo el puerto https, con todas las direcciones abiertas 0.0.0.0/0 si me permite conectarme, sin embargo al colocar mi ip pública nunca me llego a conectar a la instancia.

Comment: Si estás en una organización (por ejemplo la red de la universidad), es probable que determinado tráfico, por ejemplo el HTTP, se redirija por una vía diferente al resto. Es decir, tu IP pública HTTP puede ser diferente de tu IP pública usando SSH.

Comment: También puede suceder que el tráfico a AWS esté redirigido por una VPN, en cuyo caso tu IP pública nunca se usará para conectarse a AWS